# Update jsonb array one element without key using jsonb_set in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, set, jsonb, array-key

I have table `audits` with jsonb field `data` and it has content:

```
"products": [
    {"id": 405, "color": null, "price": 850, "title": "test", "value": 52, "real_value": 105 }, 
    {"id": 347, "color": null, "price": 195, "title": "test2", "value": 69, "real_value": 0}
]
```

For update, one needs to know the key of the element, but I don't know how to find the key of this element(0). Example:

`UPDATE audits set data = jsonb_set(data::jsonb,'{"products",0,"real_value"}','125')
where id = 10 and enterprise_id = 1;`

I tried using this:

`SELECT ( select index from
generate_series(0, jsonb_array_length(data->'products') - 1) as index
where data->'products'->index->>'id' = '347') as index_of_element
FROM audits;` but it's a very hard operation for pg.

Also I know how to find the product id for this object:

`select id as possiton from audits
where data->'products'  @> '[{"id":347}]';` but not key in array(((

Maybe I can use another function to update an item in an array, but I do not know how.

Comment: I lost myself in explanations - whats the expected result?..

Comment: I don't know how quick update only first element in jsonb array.

Comment: you did it with index 0...

Comment: if i want update other element?